# Resizing Images Constantly Through Javascript. TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to right a script that will resize images as the browser window scales. However, I get this error in the console when I refresh the site:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

In addition, if there is a function which is called every time the user resizes the window, that would be useful as well. Here is my javascript:

```
`var skill_logos = [],

console,

skill_logos_container = document.getElementById("skills-container"),

code_logo = document.getElementById("code-logo"),

design_logo = document.getElementById("design-logo"),

profile_picture = document.getElementById("profile-picture"),

school_logo = document.getElementById("school-logo"),

tech_logo = document.getElementById("tech-logo");
```

skill_logos = [code_logo, design_logo, profile_picture, school_logo, tech_logo];

function update() {

```
"use strict";

var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < skill_logos.length; i = i + 1) {

    skill_logos[i].offsetHeight = skill_logos[i].offsetWidth * skill_logos_container.offsetWidth / skill_logos_container.offsetHeight;

    console.log("Yes!");
}
```

}

update();

setInterval(update(), 5000);`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A value of null usually indicates that the element doesn't exist. Place a console.log statement after each getElementById statement to find out which one is causing the error i.e. school_logo = document.getElementById("school-logo"); console.log("school-logo",school_logo);

Comment: I think there's probably a couple issues here-- one is that you're iterating over a `document.getElementById` and presumably there's only 1 unique ID. second, I'm betting the selector is turning up null (perhaps because you're starting the script before the DOM is ready). Make sure the element exists by consoling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use css not js !
What you are trying to do can be easily done using css :

```
<img src="logo.jpg" style="min-width:5%;max-width:5%;">
```

Percent in css means percent of current page size, so in this case combining min and max width always get 5% of your page width for logo image

Comment: In my css I am already sizing and positioning images using percentages. However, the issue that I have is that when the page widens, but doesn't grow taller, the images stretch and warp.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought there must be a simpler way but didn't know what it was. Once again, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To assign your function to be called on window resize, do the following:

```
window.onresize = update;
```

As other commentators have noted, the null error is most likely occurring because the element doesn't exist at the time it's being called. Use a tool like the Chrome debugger to ensure the DOM is in the state you think it is when the function is being called